# Using multiple (owl) carousel on a single page

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel, owl-carousel

I have been looking at ways on google to use multiple carousel on a single page and yet did not find any of the solutions working for me. Can anyone of you please help.

Here is the code:

**HTML**

```
<!-- Carousel 1 -->
<div id="demo">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span12">
                <div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel">
                    <div class="item">
                        <h1>1</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <h1>2</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <h1>3</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <h1>4</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <h1>5</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <h1>6</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <h1>7</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <h1>8</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <h1>9</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <h1>10</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="customNavigation"> <a class="btn prev">Previous</a> <a class="btn next">Next</a> </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Carousel 2 -->
<div id="demo1">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span12">
                <div id="owl-demo-1" class="owl-carousel">
                    <div class="item">
                        <h1>1</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <h1>2</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <h1>3</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <h1>4</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <h1>5</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <h1>6</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <h1>7</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <h1>8</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <h1>9</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <h1>10</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="customNavigation"> <a class="btn prev">Previous</a> <a class="btn next">Next</a> </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have named the carousel as as owl-demo and owl-demo-1

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var owl = $("#owl-demo");
  owl.owlCarousel({

  items : 6, //10 items above 1000px browser width
  itemsDesktop : [1000,6], //5 items between 1000px and 901px
  itemsDesktopSmall : [900,3], // 3 items betweem 900px and 601px
  itemsTablet: [600,2], //2 items between 600 and 0;
  itemsMobile : false // itemsMobile disabled - inherit from itemsTablet option

  });

  // Custom Navigation Events
  $(".next").click(function(){owl.trigger('owl.next');})
  $(".prev").click(function(){owl.trigger('owl.prev');})


});
```

On [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wtg76spd/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Updated code should look like this: https://jsfiddle.net/wtg76spd/1/

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#owl-demo, #owl-demo-1").each(function() {
    $(this).owlCarousel({
      items : 6, //10 items above 1000px browser width
      itemsDesktop : [1000,6], //5 items between 1000px and 901px
      itemsDesktopSmall : [900,3], // 3 items betweem 900px and 601px
      itemsTablet: [600,2], //2 items between 600 and 0;
      itemsMobile : false // itemsMobile disabled - inherit from itemsTablet option
    });
  });
  // Custom Navigation Events
  $(".next").click(function(){$(this).closest('.span12').find('.owl-carousel').trigger('owl.next');})
  $(".prev").click(function(){$(this).closest('.span12').find('.owl-carousel').trigger('owl.prev');})
});
```

CSS (just first line changed):

```
//before
 #owl-demo .item{
//after
 #owl-demo .item, #owl-demo-1 .item{
//class "owl-demo" would do better in this case
```

1) Use .each() instead of copying code.

2) It'd be better to use class instead of #owl-demo and #owl-demo-1 - let's say you had not 2 but 100 sliders. Would you still give them IDs? However I didn't change it in example.

3) I used closest() and find() methods for next/prev buttons. This way I have 2 callback functions instead of 4.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.course-carousel').owlCarousel({
        items:3,
        loop:true,
        margin:10,
        nav:true,
        autoplay:true,
        autoplayTimeout:3000,
        autoplayHoverPause:true,
//   responsive:{
//       0:{
//           items:1
//       },
//       600:{
//           items:3
//       },
//       1000:{
//           items:5
//       }
//   }
  })

  $('.video-carousel').owlCarousel({
    items:1,
    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    nav:true,
    autoplay:true,
    autoplayTimeout:3000,
    autoplayHoverPause:true,
//   responsive:{
//       0:{
//           items:1
//       },
//       600:{
//           items:3
//       },
//       1000:{
//           items:5
//       }
//   }
})


  });
```

```css
body {
    color: #828bb2;
    font-family: "Roboto",sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 1.625em;
    position: relative;
}
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{
    font-family: "Playfair Display",serif;
    color: #222;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    font-weight: 900;
}
.home-banner-area {
    background: url('../images/home-banner.png') no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    max-height: 1200px;
}
.container{
    max-width:1140px;
}
.default-header {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 9;
}
.col-link{
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 20px;
}
.banner-lt-content {
    font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
    font-size: 48px;
    line-height: 1em;
    font-weight: 900;
}
.feature-area .container-fluid {
    padding-left: 50px;
}
.feature-area{
    margin-top:-110px;
}
.mt-20{
    margin-top:20px;
}
.mb-40{
    margin-bottom:40px;
}
.mb-20{
    margin-bottom:20px;
}
.mt-30{
    margin-top:30px;
}
.ml-20{
    margin-left:20px;
}
.feature-item {
    margin: 30px 0;
    border-right: 1px solid rgba(130,139,178,.2);
    padding-right: 20px;
}
.fa-book,.fa-trophy,.fa-desktop{
    font-size:30px;
}
.feature-item h4 {
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.section-gap {
    padding: 120px 0;
}
.section-title p {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    max-width: 620px;
}
.section-title h2 {
    font-size: 42px;
    color: #222;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.popular-course-area .container-fluid {
    max-width: 1140px;
    padding-left: 15px;
}
.owl-carousel .owl-item{
    padding:10px !important;
}
.course-heading{
    font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
    width:100%;
    color:#000;
    text-align:justify;
    margin:15px 0px;
    font-size:21px;
   
}
.owl-carousel .owl-item:hover .course-heading{
color:#7c32ff;
}
.video-area{
    background: url('../images/video-area-bg.webp') no-repeat;
background-position-x: center;
}
.section-gap-bottom{
    padding-bottom:120px;
}
.section-title p{
    margin-bottom:0;
    max-width:620px;
}
.video-area .video-left {
    padding-bottom: 151px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>College theme</title>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Playfair+Display:ital,wght@0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,900;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fontawesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" integrity="sha512-tS3S5qG0BlhnQROyJXvNjeEM4UpMXHrQfTGmbQ1gKmelCxlSEBUaxhRBj/EFTzpbP4RVSrpEikbmdJobCvhE3g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>
  <body>
    <header class="default-header">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
            <div class="container-fluid">
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Eclipse</a>
              <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
              </button>
              <div class="collapse navbar-collapse  justify-content-end align-items-center" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link col-link" aria-current="page" href="#">HOME</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link col-link" href="#">ABOUT US</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link col-link" href="#">COURSES</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link col-link" href="#">FACULTY</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link col-link" href="#">BLOG</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link col-link" href="#">CONTACT US</a>
                  </li>
                  <!-- <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                      Dropdown
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                      <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
                      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link disabled">Disabled</a>
                  </li> -->
                </ul>
                <form class="d-flex" role="search">
                  <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                  <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </nav>
    </header>
    <section class="home-banner-area">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row justify-content-center fullscreen align-items-center" style="height:820px;">
                <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-8 home-banner-left">
                    <h1 class="text-white banner-lt-content">Take the first step to learn with us</h1>
                    <p class="mx-auto text-white mt-20 mb-40">
                        In the history of modern astronomy, there is probably no one
                        greater leap forward than the building and launch of the space
                        telescope known as the Hubble.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="offset-lg-2 col-lg-5 col-md-12 home-banner-right">
                    <img src="images/banner-image.webp" alt="" class="img-fluid">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="feature-area">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-6">
                    <div class="feature-item d-flex">
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-book"></i>
                        <div class="ml-20">
                            <h4>New Classes</h4>
                            <p>
                                In the history of modern astronomy, there is probably no one greater leap forward.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-6">
                    <div class="feature-item d-flex">
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-trophy"></i>
                        <div class="ml-20">
                            <h4>Top Courses</h4>
                            <p>
                                In the history of modern astronomy, there is probably no one greater leap forward.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-6">
                    <div class="feature-item d-flex">
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-desktop"></i>
                        <div class="ml-20">
                            <h4>Full E-Books</h4>
                            <p>
                                In the history of modern astronomy, there is probably no one greater leap forward.
                              </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="popular-course-area section-gap">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row justify-content-center section-title">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <h2>Popular Courses<br/> Available Right Now</h2>
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
                        eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="owl-carousel course-carousel owl-theme">
              <div class="item"><img src="https://preview.colorlib.com/theme/eclipse/img/popular-course/xp4.jpg.pagespeed.ic.mfBvHveSmO.webp">
                <div class="details">
                  <div class="d-flex justify-content-between mb-20 text-center">
                    <h4 class="course-heading">B.Tech in Computer Science</h4>
                    
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="item"><img src="https://preview.colorlib.com/theme/eclipse/img/popular-course/xp4.jpg.pagespeed.ic.mfBvHveSmO.webp">
                <div class="details">
                  <div class="d-flex justify-content-between mb-20 text-center">
                    <h4 class="course-heading">B.Tech in Computer Science</h4>
                    
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="item"><img src="https://preview.colorlib.com/theme/eclipse/img/popular-course/xp4.jpg.pagespeed.ic.mfBvHveSmO.webp">
                <div class="details">
                  <div class="d-flex justify-content-between mb-20 text-center">
                    <h4 class="course-heading">B.Tech in Computer Science</h4>
                    
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="video-area section-gap-bottom">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row align-items-center">
            <div class="col-lg-5">
                <div class="section-title text-white">
                  <h2 class="text-white">
                    Watch Our Teacher<br/>in Live Action
                  </h2>
                  <p>
                    In the history of modern astronomy, there is probably no one greater leap forward than the building and
                    launch of the space telescope known as the Hubble.
                  </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="offset-lg-1 col-md-6 video-left">
              <div class="owl-carousel video-carousel owl-theme">
              
                    <div class="single-video">
                        <div class="video-part">
                            <img src="images/video-overlay-image.webp">
                        </div>
                        <h4 class="text-white mb-20 mt-30">Learn Angular js Course for Legendary Persons</h4>
                        <p class="text-white mb-20">
                          In the history of modern astronomy, there is probably no one greater leap forward than the building and
                          launch of the space telescope known as the Hubble.
                          </p>
                      </div>
                      <div class="single-video">
                        <div class="video-part">
                            <img src="https://preview.colorlib.com/theme/eclipse/img/xvideo-img.jpg.pagespeed.ic.WgYvcPV4nx.webp">
                        </div>
                        <h4 class="text-white mb-20 mt-30">Learn Angular js Course for Legendary Persons</h4>
                        <p class="text-white mb-20">
                          In the history of modern astronomy, there is probably no one greater leap forward than the building and
                          launch of the space telescope known as the Hubble.
                          </p>
                      </div>
                      <div class="single-video">
                        <div class="video-part">
                            <img src="https://preview.colorlib.com/theme/eclipse/img/xvideo-img.jpg.pagespeed.ic.WgYvcPV4nx.webp">
                        </div>
                        <h4 class="text-white mb-20 mt-30">Learn Angular js Course for Legendary Persons</h4>
                        <p class="text-white mb-20">
                          In the history of modern astronomy, there is probably no one greater leap forward than the building and
                          launch of the space telescope known as the Hubble.
                          </p>
                      </div>
                      
                     
                    
                      
                     
                    
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   
    <!-- <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-IDwe1+LCz02ROU9k972gdyvl+AESN10+x7tBKgc9I5HFtuNz0wWnPclzo6p9vxnk" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> -->
    <script src="js/all.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/fontawesome.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-o88AwQnZB+VDvE9tvIXrMQaPlFFSUTR+nldQm1LuPXQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js" integrity="sha512-bPs7Ae6pVvhOSiIcyUClR7/q2OAsRiovw4vAkX+zJbw3ShAeeqezq50RIIcIURq7Oa20rW2n2q+fyXBNcU9lrw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please explain what this code does.