# Owl Carousel not showing properly

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, owl-carousel

I am trying to load my dynamic categories with owl carousel but it shows items closed.

## Screenshots

`first category **Notebook** is opened and others are closed`

[image: one]

`second category **PC** is opened and others are closed`

[image: two]

**I need all of them to be open and show items when page loads**. it's working fine if i use html version but when i add my dynamic codes it broke as you see in images above.

## Code

```
<div class="category-module" id="latest_category">
  <h3 class="subtitle">{{$kis->title}} - <a class="viewall" href="category.tpl">view all</a></h3>
  <div class="category-module-content">

    <!-- tabs -->
    <ul id="sub-cat" class="tabs">
      @foreach($kis->childs->take(6) as $child)
      <li><a href="#tab-cat{{$child->id}}">{{$child->title}}</a></li>
      @endforeach
    </ul>

    <!-- items -->
    @foreach($kis->childs->take(6) as $child)
      <div id="tab-cat{{$child->id}}" class="tab_content">
        <div class="owl-carousel latest_category_tabs">
          @foreach($child->products->take(10) as $ki)
          <div class="product-thumb">
            <div class="image"><a href="product.html"><img src="image/product/samsung_tab_1-200x200.jpg" alt="Aspire Ultrabook Laptop" title="Aspire Ultrabook Laptop" class="img-responsive" /></a></div>
            <div class="caption">
              <h4><a href="product.html">{{$ki->title}}</a></h4>
              <p class="price"> <span class="price-new">{{number_format($ki->price,0)}}</span> <span class="price-old">$241.99</span> <span class="saving">-5%</span> </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          @endforeach
        </div>
      </div>
    @endforeach
  </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone help me to find the issue?

> PS: in case you wonder why my PHP codes are the way you see in my code
>   I am using laravel blade templates.

## Update

here i share my full html version of code above maybe you can find some differences which i couldn't

```
<div class="category-module" id="latest_category">
  <h3 class="subtitle">Electronics - <a class="viewall" href="category.tpl">view all</a></h3>
  <div class="category-module-content">
    <ul id="sub-cat" class="tabs">
      <li><a href="#tab-cat1">Laptops</a></li>
      <!-- and more -->
    </ul>
    <div id="tab-cat1" class="tab_content">
      <div class="owl-carousel latest_category_tabs">
        <div class="product-thumb">
          <div class="image"><a href="product.html"><img src="image/product/samsung_tab_1-200x200.jpg" alt="Aspire Ultrabook Laptop" title="Aspire Ultrabook Laptop" class="img-responsive" /></a></div>
          <div class="caption">
            <h4><a href="product.html">Aspire Ultrabook Laptop</a></h4>
            <p class="price"> <span class="price-new">$230.00</span> <span class="price-old">$241.99</span> <span class="saving">-5%</span> </p>
            <div class="rating"> <span class="fa fa-stack"><i class="fa fa-star fa-stack-2x"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-stack-2x"></i></span> <span class="fa fa-stack"><i class="fa fa-star fa-stack-2x"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-stack-2x"></i></span> <span class="fa fa-stack"><i class="fa fa-star fa-stack-2x"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-stack-2x"></i></span> <span class="fa fa-stack"><i class="fa fa-star fa-stack-2x"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-stack-2x"></i></span> <span class="fa fa-stack"><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-stack-2x"></i></span> </div>
          </div>
          <div class="button-group">
            <button class="btn-primary" type="button" onClick=""><span>Add to Cart</span></button>
            <div class="add-to-links">
              <button type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Add to wishlist" onClick=""><i class="fa fa-heart"></i></button>
              <button type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Add to compare" onClick=""><i class="fa fa-exchange"></i></button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="product-thumb">
          <div class="image"><a href="product.html"><img src="image/product/macbook_pro_1-200x200.jpg" alt=" Strategies for Acquiring Your Own Laptop " title=" Strategies for Acquiring Your Own Laptop " class="img-responsive" /></a></div>
          <div class="caption">
            <h4><a href="product.html"> Strategies for Acquiring Your Own Laptop </a></h4>
            <p class="price"> <span class="price-new">$1,400.00</span> <span class="price-old">$1,900.00</span> <span class="saving">-26%</span> </p>
          </div>
          <div class="button-group">
            <button class="btn-primary" type="button" onClick=""><span>Add to Cart</span></button>
            <div class="add-to-links">
              <button type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Add to wishlist" onClick=""><i class="fa fa-heart"></i></button>
              <button type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Add to compare" onClick=""><i class="fa fa-exchange"></i></button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="product-thumb">
          <div class="image"><a href="product.html"><img src="image/product/macbook_air_1-200x200.jpg" alt="Laptop Silver black" title="Laptop Silver black" class="img-responsive" /></a></div>
          <div class="caption">
            <h4><a href="product.html">Laptop Silver black</a></h4>
            <p class="price"> <span class="price-new">$1,142.00</span> <span class="price-old">$1,202.00</span> <span class="saving">-5%</span> </p>
          </div>
          <div class="button-group">
            <button class="btn-primary" type="button" onClick=""><span>Add to Cart</span></button>
            <div class="add-to-links">
              <button type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Add to wishlist" onClick=""><i class="fa fa-heart"></i></button>
              <button type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Add to compare" onClick=""><i class="fa fa-exchange"></i></button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="product-thumb">
          <div class="image"><a href="product.html"><img src="image/product/macbook_1-200x200.jpg" alt="Ideapad Yoga 13-59341124 Laptop" title="Ideapad Yoga 13-59341124 Laptop" class="img-responsive" /></a></div>
          <div class="caption">
            <h4><a href="product.html">Ideapad Yoga 13-59341124 Laptop</a></h4>
            <p class="price"> $2.00 </p>
            <div class="rating"> <span class="fa fa-stack"><i class="fa fa-star fa-stack-2x"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-stack-2x"></i></span> <span class="fa fa-stack"><i class="fa fa-star fa-stack-2x"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-stack-2x"></i></span> <span class="fa fa-stack"><i class="fa fa-star fa-stack-2x"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-stack-2x"></i></span> <span class="fa fa-stack"><i class="fa fa-star fa-stack-2x"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-stack-2x"></i></span> <span class="fa fa-stack"><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-stack-2x"></i></span> </div>
          </div>
          <div class="button-group">
            <button class="btn-primary" type="button" onClick=""><span>Add to Cart</span></button>
            <div class="add-to-links">
              <button type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Add to wishlist" onClick=""><i class="fa fa-heart"></i></button>
              <button type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Add to compare" onClick=""><i class="fa fa-exchange"></i></button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="product-thumb">
          <div class="image"><a href="product.html"><img src="image/product/ipod_shuffle_1-200x200.jpg" alt="Hp Pavilion G6 2314ax Notebok Laptop" title="Hp Pavilion G6 2314ax Notebok Laptop" class="img-responsive" /></a></div>
          <div class="caption">
            <h4><a href="product.html">Hp Pavilion G6 2314ax Notebok Laptop</a></h4>
            <p class="price"> $122.00 </p>
          </div>
          <div class="button-group">
            <button class="btn-primary" type="button" onClick=""><span>Add to Cart</span></button>
            <div class="add-to-links">
              <button type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Add to wishlist" onClick=""><i class="fa fa-heart"></i></button>
              <button type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Add to compare" onClick=""><i class="fa fa-exchange"></i></button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="product-thumb">
          <div class="image"><a href="product.html"><img src="image/product/ipod_touch_1-200x200.jpg" alt="Samsung Galaxy S4" title="Samsung Galaxy S4" class="img-responsive" /></a></div>
          <div class="caption">
            <h4><a href="product.html">Samsung Galaxy S4</a></h4>
            <p class="price"> <span class="price-new">$62.00</span> <span class="price-old">$122.00</span> <span class="saving">-50%</span> </p>
          </div>
          <div class="button-group">
            <button class="btn-primary" type="button" onClick=""><span>Add to Cart</span></button>
            <div class="add-to-links">
              <button type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Add to wishlist" onClick=""><i class="fa fa-heart"></i></button>
              <button type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Add to compare" onClick=""><i class="fa fa-exchange"></i></button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- and more -->
  </div>
</div>
```

## update 2

this is javascript of my carousels

```
$("#latest_category .owl-carousel.latest_category_tabs").owlCarousel({
    itemsCustom : [[320, 2],[600, 2],[768, 3],[992, 5],[1199, 5]],
    lazyLoad : true,
    navigation : true,
    navigationText: ['<i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>', '<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>'],
    scrollPerPage : true,
    pagination: false,
});
$("#latest_category .tab_content").addClass("deactive");
$("#latest_category .tab_content:first").show();
//Default Action
$("#latest_category ul#sub-cat li:first").addClass("active").show(); //Activate first tab
//On Click Event
$("#latest_category ul#sub-cat li").on("click", function() {
    $("#latest_category ul#sub-cat li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
    $(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
    $("#latest_category .tab_content").hide(); 
    var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); //Find the rel attribute value to identify the active tab + content
    $(activeTab).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active content
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Are you using some other code for tabs? that would be where the issue lies.

Comment: @CUGreen no just the javascript for owl carousel which is include all this classes you see in my code. As i mentioned if html version will work nicely

Comment: Then how do the tabs work?

Comment: @CUGreen tabs get class by javascript let me update my question again.

Comment: @CUGreen updated

Comment: You'll need to call owl carousel in the callback on each slider separately, if you only have one call, it will only open the first one it matches. I found an example of this here: https://codepen.io/leetech/pres/OyKmxB

Comment: @NathanielFlick how would i do that? i already tried to get my carousels by class.

Comment: See the link I posted in my previous comment, each carousel called by a unique class or id to bind it to the Owl Carousel functions.

Comment: @NathanielFlick just a question, based n your sample link i should have different classes or id's well i can add id's to my classes just like tabs i did but the problem is my script is loading from js file and it isn't inline coding so how can i pass that id in my blade to my js file?

Comment: You can also use each to find each slider: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39685863/using-multiple-owl-carousel-on-a-single-page. As long as you bind to your owl carousel id you can use each to find each of them, no matter how many.

Comment: @NathanielFlick i did each just now result is same but something is not right, when i click on tabs of `notbook` slider and `pc` slider it jumps in between! meaning it counts this two slider tabs as 1 slider tabs. how that's possible?

Comment: do you have multiple divs with the same id ```#latest_category```?

Comment: @CUGreen yes. it's looping so all my sliders have this id.

Comment: Element ids should be unique.

Comment: @CUGreen i just changed it to class and edited my js code to use class but no difference

Comment: if any tabs are hidden, are they in the DOM on page load?

Comment: @NathanielFlick yes they are, also here is small video i made of my sliders you can see how they behave https://streamable.com/v9a5m

Comment: @NathanielFlick no idea?

Comment: @CUGreen any suggestion?

Comment: Do you have a url we can look at? hard to diagnose otherwise.

Comment: i can share my local by ngrok to you

Comment: @NathanielFlick http://368ee194.ngrok.io here you go

Comment: @NathanielFlick found anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, the issue is not with the carousel. It is with the tabs script.

So you are better off using a class as the selector.

It looks like you are using something like this https://gist.github.com/hong6/7372763 for your tabs.

Then you are better off removing the `#latest_category` and using a class. Then in your jquery, you can add a jquery context. Here is un-tested the code:

```
$(".category-module .owl-carousel.latest_category_tabs").owlCarousel({
    itemsCustom : [[320, 2],[600, 2],[768, 3],[992, 5],[1199, 5]],
    lazyLoad : true,
    navigation : true,
    navigationText: ['<i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>', '<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>'],
    scrollPerPage : true,
    pagination: false,
});

$(".category-module").each(function() {
    $(".tab_content", this).addClass("deactive");
    $(".tab_content:first", this).show();
    //Default Action
    $("ul#sub-cat li:first", this).addClass("active").show(); //Activate first tab
});

//On Click Event
$(".category-module ul#sub-cat li").on("click", function() {
    var parent = $(this).parents('.category-module')
    $("ul#sub-cat li", parent).removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
    $(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
    $(".tab_content", parent).hide(); 
    var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); //Find the rel attribute value to identify the active tab + content
    $(activeTab, parent).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active content
    return false;
});
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fhawts7e/2/) that shows a similar situation.

Comment: i already changed it to class but i try with your js code as well and let you know, thanks.